# Prometheus container continuously crashes and restarts

Tags: prometheus

I run the following commands on both an ubuntu 20.04 VM with 6GB ram and 3 core CPU AND an Ubuntu 20.04 Google Cloud Instance with 4GB ram and 2 core CPU (e2-medium):

I run, as the root user:

```
git clone https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus.git
cd prometheus
docker compose up
```

This shows the normal logs (I can't fit them all here so I've started a little way into the Prometheus container logs):

```
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:15.117919521Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:15.126931519Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:15.126963347Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 169 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc42014dee0, 0x13, 0x7050001, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc4203d4a80, 0xc42046e5f8, 0x7373bf, 0xc)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc420318f80, 0x290a240, 0xc420318fc0, 0xc42014dee0, 0x13, 0xc420120a80, 0x1, 0x777dd5)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc420318f80, 0x290a240, 0xc420318fc0, 0xc420120a80, 0xc420320110, 0xc42014dee0, 0x13)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.053300315Z caller=main.go:499 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.053321002Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.059793013Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.05981778Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.060783302Z caller=main.go:486 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 307 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc4205343a0, 0xe, 0xc420520001, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc420f7ef60, 0xc420130840, 0x60, 0xc420523660)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc420be3040, 0x290a240, 0xc420be3080, 0xc4205343a0, 0xe, 0xc4201303c0, 0x155d594, 0x2)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc420be3040, 0x290a240, 0xc420be3080, 0xc4201303c0, 0xc42044db70, 0xc4205343a0, 0xe)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-alertmanager-1   | ts=2022-06-11T02:12:16.112Z caller=cluster.go:705 level=info component=cluster msg="gossip not settled" polls=0 before=0 now=1 elapsed=2.000218836s
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Starting Grafana" version=8.5.5 commit=d32ae18909 branch=HEAD compiled=2022-06-06T18:50:28Z
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="The state of unified alerting is still not defined. The decision will be made during as we run the database migrations"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config loaded from" file=/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config loaded from" file=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from command line" arg="default.paths.data=/var/lib/grafana"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from command line" arg="default.paths.logs=/var/log/grafana"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from command line" arg="default.paths.plugins=/var/lib/grafana/plugins"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from command line" arg="default.paths.provisioning=/etc/grafana/provisioning"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from command line" arg="default.log.mode=console"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_PATHS_DATA=/var/lib/grafana"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_PATHS_LOGS=/var/log/grafana"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_PATHS_PLUGINS=/var/lib/grafana/plugins"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING=/etc/grafana/provisioning"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=*********"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Config overridden from Environment variable" var="GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Path Home" path=/usr/share/grafana
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Path Data" path=/var/lib/grafana
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Path Logs" path=/var/log/grafana
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Path Plugins" path=/var/lib/grafana/plugins
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Path Provisioning" path=/etc/grafana/provisioning
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=settings t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="App mode production"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=sqlstore t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.7+0000 lvl=info msg="Connecting to DB" dbtype=sqlite3
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=migrator t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.74+0000 lvl=info msg="Starting DB migrations"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=migrator t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.75+0000 lvl=info msg="migrations completed" performed=0 skipped=392 duration=352.472µs
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=plugin.manager t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.81+0000 lvl=info msg="Plugin registered" pluginId=input
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=query_data t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.81+0000 lvl=info msg="Query Service initialization"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=live.push_http t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.81+0000 lvl=info msg="Live Push Gateway initialization"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=provisioning.datasources t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.89+0000 lvl=info msg="deleted datasource based on configuration" name=Prometheus
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=provisioning.datasources t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.89+0000 lvl=info msg="inserting datasource from configuration " name=Prometheus uid=PBFA97CFB590B2093
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=provisioning.plugins t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.94+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to read plugin provisioning files from directory" path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins error="open /etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins: no such file or directory"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=provisioning.notifiers t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.94+0000 lvl=eror msg="Can't read alert notification provisioning files from directory" path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers error="open /etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers: no such file or directory"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=ngalert t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.94+0000 lvl=info msg="warming cache for startup"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=grafanaStorageLogger t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.94+0000 lvl=info msg="storage starting"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=ngalert.multiorg.alertmanager t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.95+0000 lvl=info msg="starting MultiOrg Alertmanager"
prometheus-grafana-1        | logger=http.server t=2022-06-11T02:12:16.95+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" address=[::]:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.037992938Z caller=main.go:225 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.1.0, branch=HEAD, revision=85f23d82a045d103ea7f3c89a91fba4a93e6367a)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.038027848Z caller=main.go:226 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@6e784304d3ff, date=20180119-12:01:23)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.038037127Z caller=main.go:227 host_details="(Linux 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 65f714297c82 (none))"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.038045055Z caller=main.go:228 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.040298318Z caller=main.go:499 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.040338152Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.044159356Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.04418791Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.048291962Z caller=main.go:486 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 316 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc42032cb10, 0xe, 0x1, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc420dd2c60, 0xc4200914a0, 0x60, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc4201b6780, 0x290a240, 0xc4201b67c0, 0xc42032cb10, 0xe, 0xc420090ea0, 0x155d594, 0x2)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc4201b6780, 0x290a240, 0xc4201b67c0, 0xc420090ea0, 0xc420016e80, 0xc42032cb10, 0xe)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.962061071Z caller=main.go:225 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.1.0, branch=HEAD, revision=85f23d82a045d103ea7f3c89a91fba4a93e6367a)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.962095343Z caller=main.go:226 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@6e784304d3ff, date=20180119-12:01:23)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.962105247Z caller=main.go:227 host_details="(Linux 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 65f714297c82 (none))"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.96211469Z caller=main.go:228 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.964632811Z caller=main.go:499 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.967349007Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.976956408Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.976978012Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:17.977847651Z caller=main.go:486 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 316 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc420556270, 0xe, 0xc420950001, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc421028ae0, 0xc4209575c8, 0x458c80, 0xc42010f380)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc42053a0c0, 0x290a240, 0xc42053a100, 0xc420556270, 0xe, 0xc420124600, 0xc420957778, 0x4741d4)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc42053a0c0, 0x290a240, 0xc42053a100, 0xc420124600, 0xc4201f3a20, 0xc420556270, 0xe)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.268107791Z caller=main.go:225 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.1.0, branch=HEAD, revision=85f23d82a045d103ea7f3c89a91fba4a93e6367a)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.268140514Z caller=main.go:226 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@6e784304d3ff, date=20180119-12:01:23)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.268149497Z caller=main.go:227 host_details="(Linux 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 65f714297c82 (none))"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.268157011Z caller=main.go:228 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.27019503Z caller=main.go:499 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.270209973Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.276551691Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:19.276575684Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 266 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc42031a3e0, 0xe, 0x400001, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc420ffef60, 0x7f142e99aa50, 0xc4201e4480, 0x29d9d40)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc42013fc40, 0x290a240, 0xc42013fc80, 0xc42031a3e0, 0xe, 0xc4204c8240, 0x155d594, 0x2)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc42013fc40, 0x290a240, 0xc42013fc80, 0xc4204c8240, 0xc42031a010, 0xc42031a3e0, 0xe)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.384275376Z caller=main.go:225 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.1.0, branch=HEAD, revision=85f23d82a045d103ea7f3c89a91fba4a93e6367a)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.384311163Z caller=main.go:226 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@6e784304d3ff, date=20180119-12:01:23)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.3843208Z caller=main.go:227 host_details="(Linux 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 65f714297c82 (none))"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.384329068Z caller=main.go:228 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.385676072Z caller=main.go:499 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.385704699Z caller=web.go:383 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.389219988Z caller=main.go:509 msg="TSDB started"
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.389242669Z caller=main.go:585 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus-prometheus-1     | level=info ts=2022-06-11T02:12:21.390548672Z caller=main.go:486 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
prometheus-prometheus-1     | panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
prometheus-prometheus-1     | 
prometheus-prometheus-1     | goroutine 318 [running]:
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns.ClientConfigFromFile(0x1bfd5b1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns/clientconfig.go:86 +0xad6
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.lookupWithSearchPath(0xc42012f190, 0xe, 0x1, 0x28ef2c0, 0xc421014180, 0xc420212d80, 0x60, 0x0)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:246 +0x48
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refresh(0xc420446500, 0x290a240, 0xc420446540, 0xc42012f190, 0xe, 0xc420212900, 0x155d594, 0x2)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:174 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll.func1(0xc420446500, 0x290a240, 0xc420446540, 0xc420212900, 0xc420198540, 0xc42012f190, 0xe)
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:163 +0x73
prometheus-prometheus-1     | created by github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns.(*Discovery).refreshAll
prometheus-prometheus-1     |   /go/src/github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/dns/dns.go:162 +0xd3
prometheus-prometheus-1 exited with code 2
prometheus-alertmanager-1   | ts=2022-06-11T02:12:24.115Z caller=cluster.go:697 level=info component=cluster msg="gossip settled; proceeding" elapsed=10.003316232s
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Running 5/5
 ⠿ Container prometheus-node-exporter-1  Stopp...                                        0.5s
 ⠿ Container prometheus-grafana-1        Stopped                                         0.9s
 ⠿ Container prometheus-prometheus-1     Stopped                                         0.4s
 ⠿ Container prometheus-alertmanager-1   Stoppe...                                       0.4s
 ⠿ Container prometheus-cadvisor-1       Stopped                                         0.5s
canceled
```

Finally I CTRL+C as Prometheus kept restarting. All the other services work.

The `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.1.0
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    links:
      - cadvisor:cadvisor
      - alertmanager:alertmanager
#      - pushgateway:pushgateway
    depends_on:
      - cadvisor
#      - pushgateway
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
#    deploy:
#      placement:
#        constraints:
#          - node.hostname == ${HOSTNAME}

  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command: 
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: global

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager/:/etc/alertmanager/
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
#    deploy:
#      placement:
#        constraints:
#          - node.hostname == ${HOSTNAME}
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: global

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    user: "472"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/config.monitoring
    networks:
      - back-tier
      - front-tier
    restart: always

#  pushgateway:
#    image: prom/pushgateway
#    restart: always
#    expose:
#      - 9091
#    ports:
#      - "9091:9091"
#    networks:
#      - back-tier
```

The `prometheus.yml`:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'my-project'

# Load and evaluate rules in this file every 'evaluation_interval' seconds.
rule_files:
  - 'alert.rules'
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

# alert
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - "alertmanager:9093"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.

  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
         - targets: ['localhost:9090']


  - job_name: 'cadvisor'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    dns_sd_configs:
    - names:
      - 'tasks.cadvisor'
      type: 'A'
      port: 8080

#     static_configs:
#          - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']

  - job_name: 'node-exporter'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    dns_sd_configs:
    - names:
      - 'tasks.node-exporter'
      type: 'A'
      port: 9100

#  - job_name: 'pushgateway'
#    scrape_interval: 10s
#    dns_sd_configs:
#    - names:
#      - 'tasks.pushgateway'
#      type: 'A'
#      port: 9091

#     static_configs:
#          - targets: ['node-exporter:9100']
```

Not sure what's going on but I find it odd that it won't run correctly on two different environments (a virtual box VM on my laptop and a Google Cloud Instance). All files can be found on the git repository for Prometheus at https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus.git

Comment: Make that 3 machines having issues. I just tried directly on my laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04 and have the same issue.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have no working deployments? I think it's unlikely that the issue is the hosts and more likely in your configuration. I suspect the DNS Discovery is failing. Both occurrences of the error in the logs is `slice bounds out of range` precede stacktraces from Prometheus' DNS discovery. You have 2 occurrences of DNS discovery and both use `tasks` prefix of the host name. It's unclear to me whether these names would resolve and that's possibly why you're getting the errors, I assume the slice corresponds to the expected set of discovered names. I'd focus on that.

Comment: I do not have any working deployments. The pushegateway task is commented out.

Comment: When I switched to the prom/prometheus:latest image it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I switched to the prom/prometheus:latest image it works. Doesn't explain why it didn't work but in case anyone is looking for a potential fix.
In the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
```